# Ag-Grid-Vue not displaying at all

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

**UPDATE:** I ended up rebuilding the page from the ground up and the grid works now. I had a weird conflict somewhere but I have no idea what it was. At least it's working now!

---

I have used `ag-grid` before but I've never run into an issue like this. We have the grid working perfectly fine on another project so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

I am using the `ag-grid-vue` wrapper to use the grid in our `Vue` application. I have copied the exact example that they give and it is not working for me. I can see the grid in the dev tools but it simply does not exist in the HTML.

[This is the exact example that I am using](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-vue-example/blob/master/src/large-data-set-example/LargeDataSetExample.vue)

I am receiving no errors in the console either. See below for screenshots of the dev tools and HTML.

[image: Dev Tools]

[image]

Currently using `Vue.js 2.6.10` and `ag-grid-vue 20.1.0`. Below is the code for the root component that imports the ag-grid component. The code for `test-grid` is identical to the example I linked to above.

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <test-grid></test-grid>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import TestGrid from './TestGrid.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            'test-grid': TestGrid
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try giving it a height?

Comment: @Aamir Yeah, I have. I originally thought that was the issue but it's not. I've tried giving the grid itself a height and the containing div but neither worked.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. What exactly did you do to resolve it?

Comment: @vab2048 Unfortunately I don't know what the issue was. I rebuilt the page and the grid worked the second time around so I don't know what was causing the issue before. Sorry, wish I could be of more help.

Comment: I have solved my issue. The issue for me was that the table was not being formatted properly (the data was semi-displayed though). I solved it by including the correct CSS files: `import '@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css'`. Thanks for the help @Quiver